# Saving the time from a datepicker

Tags: iphone, uidatepicker

I have a date picker thats is set to time. The time from the picker is shown in a textfield. I need to save the data on app exit to the NSUserDefalult and later load the time from NSUserDefalult. Also how could I save the datePickers location on the same time I used it last time.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate, I had searched earlier and couldnt find anything to do with this. I guess I wasnt searching the right keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To save the data in NSUserDefaults**

```
// create a standardUserDefaults variable
NSUserDefaults * standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// saving an NSString
[standardUserDefaults setObject:@"YOUR DATE VALUE TO BE SAVED" forKey:@"date"];

// synchronize the settings
[standardUserDefaults synchronize];
```

**To retrieve the data from NSUserDefaults**

```
// create a standardUserDefaults variable
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// Checking if the Data exists.
if([standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"date"] != nil) {

  // getting an NSString object
  NSString *myDate = [standardUserDefaults stringForKey:@"date"];

}
```

Now set the date back to `UITextField`

```
textField.text = myDate;
```

Comment: Sorry but im really new to programming and I got no idea what to do with this. where do I put the two codes? And how do I set the sate back to the textfield?

Comment: Add the save data code in your `datePickerValueChanged` method.